# VBA prints the contents of the array in the specified cell and then jumps out of the loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Thanks for watching, I have a list with urls in D and E, I need to get the value in XML and print it after F.then wrap to the next line.

```
Sub main()
    On Error Resume Next
    hang1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    If hang1 < 2 Then Exit Sub

    sz_yuan = Sheet1.Range("D2:E" & hang1)

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.async = False


    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Business_Item_Desc")

        For a = 1 To hang1 - 1
            For b = 1 To 2
                Application.StatusBar = "capture" & a & "/" & hang1 - 1 & "Article of data" & b & "/2..."
                DoEvents
                URL0 = sz_yuan(a, b)
                .Open "GET", URL0, True
                .send
                Do While .ReadyState <> 4
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                jg0 = .responseText
        
                If InStr(jg0, "<data/>") = 0 Then
                    For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
                        Sheet1.Range("F").Offset(0, i).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
                    Next i
                    Exit For
                End If
                dqhang = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            Next b
        Next a
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Among them, there is an error when the array is printed, and I want to ask how to modify it to run normally.

```
For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
    Sheet1.Range("F").Offset(0, i).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
Next i
```

[image: ways of presenting]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you say

```
Sheet1.Range("F")
```

VBA does not know what you mean.  Change it to

```
Sheet1.Range("F1")
```

And I think it will get rid of the error.

Looking at your code, you may perfer this as I think it will get you closer to the final goal

```
sheet1.cells(a,"F")
```

Comment: A good note would be to get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, which is hiding all errors.

Comment: @Gove Thank you for coming again, because the question is different so I added another question.I have a list in D1,D2,D3...E1,E2...There are URLs, but I need to put the array obtained by D1 or E1 behind F1, and then go to D2 to get the new value Put behind F2

Comment: It would help if you could show an image of your worksheet indicating where the lists are and where you need the output to go.  I've added a different variation to allow you to specify the row you want to write to.

Comment: @Gove I added image captions

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to parse the XML at the URL in cell D2 and put the found items beginning if F2. So if the XML from D2 finds three values, they will go in F2, G2, and H2.  Then you parse the XML from E2 and continue to add the values at the end of row 2, so if the XML from E2 gives 2 values, they would go in I2 and J2.  IF so, This line will do it.

```
Sheet1.Cells(sz_yuan(a, b).row, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text
```

Comment: Your direction is correct, but there is no value after I replace it, and what I want to express is that if D2 has 3 values, write F2, G2, H3, jump out of the loop, no need to read the URL of E2, start from D3 again The url read value is written to F3,G3,H3.....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but there is no value after I replace it"

Comment: I use ` Sheet1.Cells(sz_yuan(a, b).row, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text ` change `Sheet1.Range("F").Offset(0, i).Value = nodeXML.Item(i).Text` it can't work

Comment: I'm thinking of rewriting the loop using your original logic